# How frequently should Shatnez laboratories be checked?

Tags: time, hechsher-certification, beit-din-court, inspection, shaatnez

Many cities have a laboratory where individuals can take their clothes to check if there is shatnez and if necessary to remove it.

Often these laboratories are under the supervision of the local Beis Din or Kashrus Authority.

Most activities to which Botei Din give approval are regularly inspected (e.g. butcher's shops).

According to Halacho, how frequently should these laboratories be checked for their ability to detect shatnez?

Comment: Exactly how do you expect to check them. No rabbi knows the difference between wool and linen. Only through asking another certified checker to double check clothing that has already been checked.  They will always have an excuse how something got "through".  You could ask the same with sofrus or shechita.  No sofer is ever checked either.  Although his mistakes are easier to find.  I dont think you will find halachos about this.

Comment: many people do have their works that have been written by a Sofer checked over by someone else.

Comment: From what I understand most of most of the Bais Dins  and kashrush authorities do check the shatnez laboratories ever (they do not know how to) the only thing they can check is if the checker is acting as an yira shomaim

Comment: Even it is computer checked like today,  it still doesnt prove that the sofer wrote it with the correct "kavono".  The same with shechito there is no way of checking a shochet who says a torn "sircha" is kosher.  He could always tear it himself.

Comment: @hazoriz So all we can say is that the shatnez checker is a yorei shomayim who may or may not know the relevant dinim. Seems then to me that I should find out for myself whether the Beis Din has checked the **ability** of the checker to check.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok From what I understand he does not need to know almost any dinim he just needs to be able to find linen (or wool) if it is there (he usually knows better then the Rabbi how to find/recognize them so no point of testing him until the Rabbis learn for themselves (which they are not obligated to)

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. Sometimes one can use bittul like in other issurim. They also have to be connected in certain ways to be assur.  There is also a problem when like wearing two socks one of wool and one of linen where one cant really take off one without the other.